# Ruby equivalent to Python __main__

Tags: python, ruby, program-entry-point

If in a ruby file I define a function like so:

```
def tell_the_truth()
    puts "truth"
end
```

is there an equivalent to python's main?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tell_the_truth()
```

Is it to simply call the function inside the file?

```
tell_the_truth
```

Comment: The reason for the `if` in Python is to prevent the function from being called if the file is included into another one, which your Ruby example doesn't do (as far as I know)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I understand the why behind the if in python. To compare, I have tried putting tell_the_truth() just under the function definition and then importing that file from another ruby file using "require". That prints "truth". So the top level statement seem to be run when a file is imported.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
if __FILE__ == $0
    tell_the_truth()
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
    tell_the_truth()
end
```